# Installation next js

Tags: javascript, next.js, installation

I just installed next js, I haven't touched and changed the code. When I type npm run dev, there is an error like this:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/a2p40.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JHtTH.png
but the app is still running, it just looks different, not dark like it normally does.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.